# dc.js - Remove empty bins from stacked bar chart upon filtering

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter, stacked-chart

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JaelB/x1vL3ebj/58/) for a stacked bar chart. This chart filters another line chart.

To remove empty bins, I tried [dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ), [this example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/filtering-removing.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354064/remove-empty-bins-with-reduce-add-remove-function-not-working).

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886088/dc-js-stacked-bar-chart-with-empty-bin-filter-displaying-in-strange-way) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115001/elastic-x-axis-for-stacked-barchart-removing-the-empty-bins-dc-js) for a stacked bar chart scenario, but my grouping is different.
I've tried different things but I'm not able to get it to work.

Pretty sure I'm missing something simple.

Kindly review my code. Am I doing something wrong? How do i get the remove_empty_bins() working?

```
 var stack = dc.barChart('#stack');

 var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.no;});

          var YDimension_before = XDimension.group().reduce(
            function(p, d) {
              p[d.sub_no] = (p[d.sub_no]|| 0) + +d.avg;
              return p;
            },
            function(p, d) {
              p[d.sub_no] = (p[d.sub_no]|| 0) - +d.avg;
              return p;
            },
            function() {
              return {};});

         var YDimension = remove_empty_bins(YDimension_before);

      stack.width(550)
          .height(400)
          .dimension(XDimension)
          .group(YDimension, '1', sel_stack(1))
          .transitionDuration(500)
          .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
          .x(d3.scaleBand())
          .margins({left: 80, top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 80})
          .brushOn(false)
          .clipPadding(20)
          .elasticX(true)
          .elasticY(true)
          .title(function(d) {
          return [ d.key + '[' + this.layer + '] ',
                  d.value[this.layer]].join('\n')
          });
 stack.stack(YDimension, '2', sel_stack(2))
                      .stack(YDimension, '3', sel_stack(3))

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
          return {
              all:function () {
                  return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                     return d.value != 0;

                  });
              }
          };
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are reducing to an object, so `d.value` never equals zero.

You could use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any stack is non zero for each bin:

```
function remove_competely_empty_bins(source_group) {
          return {
              all:function () {
                  return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                     return Object.values(d.value).some(v => v!=0);

                  });
              }
          };
      }
```

Warning: dc.js isn't happy if the different stacks don't have the same x values. So that's why you wouldn't want to remove just the empty stacks. Only remove the bin if all the stacks are zero.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. My browser(chrome) was not supporting Object.values. So i had to recreate your function using Array.prototype.map(). Now its working fine in my browser. (Although I'm not sure how efficient my code is). Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JaelB/x1vL3ebj/71/

Comment: Oops I'm writing from mobile and wasn't able to test that. I always get confused which utilities are member functions and which are on the class. I've corrected my code above. Glad you found a different way and that the general idea worked!

Comment: link to last fiddle is broken.

Comment: Working fiddle with Gordon's answer - http://jsfiddle.net/JaelB/mgcrx7ty/